# How to generate n random numbers with a sum of m in public static void main (scanner)?

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate 4 different numbers for the second `else if` statement (`life_1.equals(a)` and another random integer for the third `else if` statement (`life_1.equals(c)` without changing the public static void main for myscanner. Thanks for answering and sorry if my question doesnt make any sense at all :/

```
System.out.println("Do you want to use a lifeline now? (y - yes or n - no)");
answer =myScanner.nextLine();


boolean life=false;

if (answer.equals("y")) {
do {


    System.out.println("Alright. Which one of your lifelines would you like to use?( f-fifty-fifty  , a-ask the audience, c-call a friend)"); 
    life_1= myScanner.nextLine();
    if (life_1.equals("f") && lifeline_5050 !=0){
      System.out.println(" The answer is not b or d");
      lifeline_5050 = lifeline_5050 - 1;

    life=true;
    }
    else if (life_1.equals("a") && lifeline_ask != 0) {
      System.out.println("The audeince say the answers are: a."+randomNum1+ "b. "+randomNum2+"c. "+randomNum3+ "d. "+randomNum4 );
      lifeline_ask= lifeline_ask -1 ; 
     life=true;
    }
    else if (life_1.equals("c") && lifeline_call !=0 ){



      System.out.println("Your friend says the answer a is "+RandomNum+" possible.");
      lifeline_call = lifeline_call -1; 
      life=true;}
    else {
      System.out.println("Invalid answer. You can't use this lifeline."); }
    }     while (life==false);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is your issue occurring? You may also have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: What is "the public static void main for myscanner" not to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate `n` numbers whose sum is `m`, you can think permutation of `m` o and `n - 1` |, then count o between | and the number of o will be the numbers generated.

For example, given that m = 10 and n = 4, the permutation may be

```
o|oooo|ooo|oo
```

Then, the results are `1, 4, 3, 2`.

To generate this permutation, you should do shuffle.

You only have to consider position of |, so the implementation may be like this:

```
int[] generateNumbers(int m, int n) {
    if(m < 0 || n <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (n == 1) return new int[]{m};
    int separatorNum = n - 1;
    int permutationLength = m + n - 1;
    int[] positions = new int[separatorNum];
    int[] result = new int[n];
    // shuffle array of o and |
    for (int i = 0; i < separatorNum; i++) {
        int p = (int)(Math.random() * (permutationLength - i)) + i;
        if (p >= separatorNum) {
            // o will be swapped with | if the number was not swapped to | before
            boolean dupe = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (positions[j] == p) {
                    dupe = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            positions[i] = (dupe ? i : p);
        } else {
            // another | will be swapped with |, so | will be here
            positions[i] =i;
        }
    }
    // sort the positions
    for (int i = positions.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (positions[j] > positions[j + 1]) {
                int temp = positions[j];
                positions[j] = positions[j + 1];
                positions[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    // decode the positions
    result[0] = positions[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
        result[i] = positions[i] - positions[i - 1] - 1;
    }
    result[n - 1] = permutationLength - positions[n - 2] - 1;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but not quite what i wanted. i need to use a shorter version of this code that would give me the same result. What i'm really trying to do is generate 4 different numbers from 1 to 100 that add up to 100 so when the user asks to use a lifeline, the program generates 4 different numbers as the percentage of the voted answers